# How to make an android service that runs a notification persistent

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want the service to keep running even when the app is killed by the phone(When it needs RAM for other apps).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only make your service persistent if you are developing system apps. These services will be basically un-killable.

Comment: What do you mean by System apps?

Comment: Your android needs to be rooted, in order to be un-killable. Even then its not easy to develope an app like this.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) which make it less likely for your service to get killed but it is still possible for it to get killed.

There is no way to guarantee you service stays alive forever